# JTabbedPane with 2 tabs is not showing up

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a program in which when a person click on label it will take you to a 2nd panel which will have 2 tabs. The problem is when I click on image label I only see blank window with no tabs and nothing in it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import static java.awt.Font.BOLD;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class hotels extends JFrame{

    JButton hotel;
    JLabel image;
    JTabbedPane tabbed,tabbed1;
    JPanel panel;
    JPanel panel1;
    Container pane;

    public hotels(){
        panel=new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        hotel=new JButton();
        hotel.setText("Hotels");

        Font myFont = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18);

        hotel.setFont(myFont);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(hotel);

        hotel.setBounds(50, 80, 100, 40);

        image=new JLabel();

        image.setBounds(50,1,80,80);
        image.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.yellow));
        image.setBackground(Color.white);
        image.setIcon(new ImageIcon("2.gif"));
        panel.add(image);

        panel1=new JPanel();

        tabbed=new JTabbedPane();

        tabbed.add( "Round Trip",panel1);
        tabbed.add("One Way",panel1);
        panel1.setVisible(false);

        panel1.revalidate();
        panel.revalidate();
        panel1.repaint();
        panel.repaint();

        pane=getContentPane();
        pane.add(tabbed);
        pane.add(panel1);
        pane.add(panel);

        image.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                if (e.getSource()==image){
                    panel1.show();
                    panel.setVisible(false);
                    panel1.setVisible(true);
                    tabbed.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        hotels mw=new hotels();
        mw.setVisible(true);
        mw.setSize(400, 400);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 pane.add(tabbed);
 pane.add(panel1);
 pane.add(panel);
```

The above code attempts to add 3 children to the Content pane's - the Content pane by default has a `BorderLayout`, which cannot have more than 1 component in it's `CENTER` position - hence the last Component added is the Component that will be seen. Your options are

1. Use a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) which allows you to change the Panel shown dynamically
2. Remove all items from the appropriate Container, then add them and revalidate/repaint

Example of 1 in link above. Example of 2 (in the `MouseListener`):

```
pane.removeAll();
pane.add(tabbed);//presuming you want tabbed to show now
pane.revalidate();//or invalidate/validate for <1.7 JRE versions
pane.repaint();
```

Comment: Thanks I update my codes but why I only see 2nd tab "one way" and don't see the other one.

Comment: See MadProgrammer's answer for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There are a series of problems, including the use of `null` layouts, which will haunt you with no end of problems...

```
 tabbed.add( "Round Trip",panel1);
 tabbed.add("One Way",panel1);
```

The above code is adding the same panel to two different tabs, but since a component can only have a single parent, it will automatically remove the "Round Trip" tab

Then...

```
    pane=getContentPane();
    pane.add(tabbed);
    pane.add(panel1);
    pane.add(panel);
```

Which removes all the tabs from the tabbed lane (for the same reason above) and, depending on what layout manager your using, may only show `panel`

You don't need to change the visibility state of your components been managed by the `JTabbedPane`, as it will take care of all that for you

See [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) for more details

Comment: so I have to use card layout for that.

Comment: For what?  `JTabbedPane` will take of the switching of the views for you automatically. The `null` layout on `panel` is what is going to haunt you